# "Given Final Block not properly padded" error in Java AES Decryption

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm making a Java Program that will read an encrypted file, and with the help of a key, it will decrypt it. I am using this [AES Encryption](http://aesencryption.net/) algorithm I found as it provided code that I also needed.

What I did was I copied the Java Class to my project. This is what my `AES.java` file looks like:

```
public class AES{
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey ;
    private static byte[] key ;

    private static String decryptedString;
    private static String encryptedString;


    public static void setKey(String myKey){


        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(key.length);
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
            System.out.println(key.length);
            System.out.println(new String(key,"UTF-8"));
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");


        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }

    public static String getDecryptedString() {
        return decryptedString;
    }

    public static void setDecryptedString(String decryptedString) {
        AES.decryptedString = decryptedString;
    }

    public static String getEncryptedString() {
        return encryptedString;
    }

    public static void setEncryptedString(String encryptedString) {
        AES.encryptedString = encryptedString;
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt){
        try{
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

            setEncryptedString(Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
            //              byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            //              setEncryptedString(new String(encodedBytes));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: "+e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt){
        try{
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt))));
            //setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt))));


        }
        catch (Exception e){

            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: "+e.toString());

        }
        return null;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){

        final String strToEncrypt = "My text to encrypt";
        final String strPssword = "encryptor key";
        AES.setKey(strPssword);

        AES.encrypt(strToEncrypt.trim());

        System.out.println("String to Encrypt: " + strToEncrypt); 
        System.out.println("Encrypted: " + AES.getEncryptedString());

        final String strToDecrypt =  AES.getEncryptedString();
        AES.decrypt(strToDecrypt.trim());

        System.out.println("String To Decrypt : " + strToDecrypt);
        System.out.println("Decrypted : " + AES.getDecryptedString());
    }
}
```

And in my `Main.java` class: I have the following:

```
//I get my encoded input as a FileInputStream
InputStream encodedInput = null;
encodedInput = new FileInputStream("./Config/config2.properties");

//get the input and then convert to Bytes then to String
//I also tried converting to String right away
byte[] inputBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(encodedInput);
String theString = IOUtils.toString(inputBytes, "UTF-8"); //IOUtils.toString(encodedInput, "UTF-8"); 
System.out.println("Input string (encoded) = " + theString);

//It stops at the decrypt call and throw the exception
AES.setKey(localProperties.getKey());
AES.decrypt(theString.trim());
String decrypted = AES.getDecryptedString();
```

As you can see, get the contents of my file. The contents are correct since I also print them at the system log.

But what I can't figure out is why the decrypt function can't decrypt it even if the function asked for a String as its input.

I'm really dumbfounded and I don't know where to start with this.

Comment: hmmm. you have PKCS5PADDING in upper case in decrypt and sentence case in encrypt. I'm not sure if this could be causing the problem, but it would be worth sticking to PKCS5Padding

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: If you have trouble with your decryption, you should show encryption. Although, EJP's answer might be helpful, I don't see why his answer would solve your problem.

Comment: The error message was not entirely clear, so I have tried to add quotes to it in order to make it clear where it begins and ends. If this needs adjusting, please do edit again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt){
```

The problem is here. This method should accept a `byte[]` parameter. You already have the ciphertext as a `byte[]` array. You are pointless converting it to a `String`, only to have to convert it back inside this method. The round-trip is not lossless. Just pass it around as the `byte[]` array.

`String` is not a container for binary data.

Comment: Okay. I replaced the argument with a `byte[]` instead of a `String`. And with this: `cipher.doFinal(byteToDecrypt)` instead. But now, I'm getting a `Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher` error. But my input has length of 344 characters and it is divisble by 16.

Comment: I made a new question instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268843/java-aes-file-decryption-input-length-not-multiple-of-16-bytes-when-using-padd

Comment: Why answer a non-answerable question?